# Is it possible to send push notification in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is it possible to send push notification in ionic framework. any code is available

Answer (score 0):

It definitely is. The Ionic documentation walks through this process (available [here](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-from-scratch)) and has code examples to show how the most common push tasks (send/receive) are done. There are also tutorials out there (just like this [one](https://www.airpair.com/ionic-framework/posts/push-notifications-using-ionic-framework)) which show practical applications utilizing push notifications.